# Unix User groups permissions

Tags: unix, permissions, user-accounts, chown

When I try to run an application I have 'moved' by zippping + unzipping from one host to another it says :`This program can only be executed by users in group 1002.`

Can Anybody please decipher what this means?

I know you do not normally zip and move an application but this is a different problem/ message than that - so concentrate on the message!

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a system message, meaning it is not related to this file's permissions. 
This message has been generated by the application you are trying to run. 
It seems the application checks if the current user, who runs the application, is a member of group 1002. So what you have to do is:

- create group 1002 and give it a meaningful name
- add the user who will run this application to this group

Comment: Perfect! Cheers mate!